# An Error Occurred: Could not resolve NavigationCase for outcome: /index

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation

I have this in my web application in JSF

```
<h:body>
        <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/areas/List" value="Show All Areas Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/aulas/List" value="Show All Aulas Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/dispositivos/List" value="Show All Dispositivos Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/edificios/List" value="Show All Edificios Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/marcas/List" value="Show All Marcas Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/modelos/List" value="Show All Modelos Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/rolesusuarios/List" value="Show All Rolesusuarios Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/tiposdispositivos/List" value="Show All Tiposdispositivos Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/usuarios/List" value="Show All Usuarios Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/valorescomandos/List" value="Show All Valorescomandos Items"/>
    <br />
    <h:link outcome="/secured/estadosdispositivos/List" value="Show All Estadosdispositivos Items"/>
    </h:body>
```

And response this error when I try access to the /areas/List.xhtml

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Could not resolve NavigationCase for outcome: /index
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:86)
```

I tried this in faces-config.xml and not run.

```
 <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/main/webapp/secured/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>index</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/main/webapp/secured/aulas/List.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

Comment: can you confirm /main folder is in the same level as WEB-INF? If so your outcomes must include the /main at the beginning. Use wildcard in from view id to debug: <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>

Comment: I confirm that /main folder an WEB-INF is in the same level. Anyway I tried use a wildcard  and not run. From JSF2 I read that is not neccesary use navigation rules to link page with other one. I tried too and not run. Thanks!!!

Comment: Solved. The problem was the path of the template.xhtml used in List.xhtml